# java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Access is denied)

Tags: java, file, file-permissions, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to create some files dynamically in my Java project root. but I get the following error when I run the code.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\POS_ALL\T_POS_NEWEST\TouchPosApplication\WebContent\zharaimages\279 (Access is denied)
```

Is it possible to write a file to the root project folder in Java? Here is the code used.

```
private void createImage(PosItemImageDTO imageDTO,String path) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = imageDTO.getPosItemImage();
        path = path + "\\";
        if(bytes!=null && bytes.length>0){
            OutputStream out = null;
            // BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
            File l = new  File(path);

            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
            out.write(bytes);

            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: What process is trying to create the file? Tomcat?

Comment: Try to write a file yourself in that folder.

Comment: This is a java process which is trying to create the folder and the files

Comment: What is your process owner? To get the information, open the Windows Task Manager, find the user name column in the Processes tab. Then right click on the directory where you are going to create files, check its security attributes in the Properties dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Its because it seems like you are trying to open and read a directory here. Your file as you say it, doesn't have any extension specified so java takes it as a directory. use `isFile()` method to check for a file before opening. You can use `listFiles()` method to obtain files of the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure `path = path + "\\";` is a correct path. If there is a directory, the program will show you `Access is denied`. You should add some checks before open the file, just like `if (l.isDirectory())`.